# Converting a SQL Server Proc to a View

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-view

I'm in the process of trying to convert the following SQL code into a view:

```
DECLARE @Date DATE
DECLARE @ID INT

SELECT @ID = SystemCalendarID,
        @Date = Date
FROM Server2.dbo.SystemCalendar
WHERE IsCurrentReportingDay = 'Y'

SELECT cp.ClientName + ' (' + CAST(cp.ClientID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' [Reporting point] ,
       icp.ClientName + ' (' + CAST(icp.ClientID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' [Issuer] ,
       RTRIM(icp.GroupName) + ' (' + CAST(icp.GroupID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' [Group] ,
       s.ClientName + ' (' + CAST(s.ClientID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' AS [Site] ,
       i.ACCode ,
       tr.SourceSystemTradeId ,
       tr.SWWR ,
       tr.SWWRError ,
       tc.SanctionerComment ,
       tc.SignOffBy ,
       tc.CompletedFlag ,
       tc.PreApprovedFlag ,
       tc.GenuineWWRFlag ,
       tc.TradeCommentsID ,
       tc.HistoryID
FROM   myapp.SWWR_NonIndex_Trades tr
       LEFT JOIN myapp.vwLatestSWWR_NonIndex_TradeComments tc ON tc.SourceSystemTradeID = tr.SourceSystemTradeId
                                                               AND tc.IsActive = 1
       INNER JOIN myapp.SWWR_NonIndex_TradeAttribs ta ON ta.TradeID = tr.TradeID
                                                       AND ta.IsActive = 1
                                                       AND ta.MaturityDate >= @Date
                                                       AND ta.TradeDate <= @Date
                                                       AND ta.ID = @ID
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client cp ON cp.ClientID = tr.ReportingPointCpartyID
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client lcp ON lcp.ClientID = tr.LegalEntityID
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client s ON s.ClientID = tr.SiteID
       LEFT JOIN myapp.Issuer i ON i.ACCode = tr.ACCode
                                 AND i.IsLatest = 1
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client icp ON icp.ClientID = COALESCE(
                                                                                   tr.CreditDerivativeUnderlyingIssuerId ,
                                                                                   i.SDS)
WHERE  tr.IsActive = 1
       AND tr.SWWR ='Y';
```

As it currently stands, this code works and pulls back the information I need. For reasons I don't want to explain, I'm wanting to convert this to a view. I know that you can't declare variables in the way I'm doing, but is there a way in which I can amend what I have to allow the use of my two variables above?

Comment: Will be good if you do not remove question content after you got the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is simpler than you think
i have moved you first select and do "1=1" kind join
and then you do not need any variables

```
CREATE VIEW XXX  
AS  
SELECT cp.ClientName + ' (' + CAST(cp.ClientID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' [Reporting point] ,
       icp.ClientName + ' (' + CAST(icp.ClientID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' [Issuer] ,
       RTRIM(icp.GroupName) + ' (' + CAST(icp.GroupID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' [Group] ,
       s.ClientName + ' (' + CAST(s.ClientID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')' AS [Site] ,
       i.ACCode ,
       tr.SourceSystemTradeId ,
       tr.SWWR ,
       tr.SWWRError ,
       tc.SanctionerComment ,
       tc.SignOffBy ,
       tc.CompletedFlag ,
       tc.PreApprovedFlag ,
       tc.GenuineWWRFlag ,
       tc.TradeCommentsID ,
       tc.HistoryID
FROM   Server2.dbo.SystemCalendar SC       
       INNER JOIN myapp.SWWR_NonIndex_Trades tr ON SC.IsCurrentReportingDay = 'Y'
       LEFT JOIN myapp.vwLatestSWWR_NonIndex_TradeComments tc ON tc.SourceSystemTradeID = tr.SourceSystemTradeId
                                                               AND tc.IsActive = 1
       INNER JOIN myapp.SWWR_NonIndex_TradeAttribs ta ON ta.TradeID = tr.TradeID
                                                       AND ta.IsActive = 1
                                                       AND ta.MaturityDate >= SC.Date
                                                       AND ta.TradeDate <= SC.Date
                                                       AND ta.ID = SC.SystemCalendarID
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client cp ON cp.ClientID = tr.ReportingPointCpartyID
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client lcp ON lcp.ClientID = tr.LegalEntityID
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client s ON s.ClientID = tr.SiteID
       LEFT JOIN myapp.Issuer i ON i.ACCode = tr.ACCode
                                 AND i.IsLatest = 1
       LEFT JOIN Server2.dbo.vwLatestReporting_Client icp ON icp.ClientID = COALESCE(
                                                                                   tr.CreditDerivativeUnderlyingIssuerId ,
                                                                                   i.SDS)
WHERE  tr.IsActive = 1
       AND tr.SWWR = 'Y';
```